# What will be the appropriate statistical test for this design please?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics, agreement-statistics

I have a data of:

30 medical students who have rated visibility of 40 brain anatomical structures (each structure has been rated on a Likert scale of 1-5, where 1 corresponds to "not visible" and 5- "clearly visible").

The research question is two-fold:

1. What is the overall concordance between the students in identifying these structures (which is measured on the 1-5 ratings ordinal scale)? Is there any statistically significance difference in between their ratings?
2. Is year of medical school study associated with rating?

[image]

Comment: 1. If you're not sure what you want to find out, we can't possibly suggest a test for it. 2. "Figure out" correlation is a question of estimation, not testing. ... please describe in the plainest possible English what the point of this study is.

Comment: Please see my edited question above. I hope it’s clearer now. I am grateful for the help, thank you.

Comment: When you say "What is the correlation" are you specifically asking about a particular kind of correlation, or is this some more general sense of association?

Comment: Sorry, but your first question is still unclear. What do you mean by "overall correlation"?  I think it might be better if you edited the question to avoid statistical terms and tell us in plain English what you are trying to find out.

Comment: I apologize for the ambiguity. I am trying to know what the correlation/association/concordance between these measurements is? Not sure if I can simplify it further. For example, if we had two students, we could use Cohen's Kappa to determine the correlation. What would be applicable in the present situation please?